# Azure Branch PR Policy - Require Source Branch Be Up-To-Date

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-repos

I'm trying to get quality branch policies on my `develop` branch and so far I've got some good basics:

- requiring reviewers to approve
- requiring all checks to pass
- limiting merge types

What I want to ensure is that a source branch in a PR must be up-to-date with its target branch. I cannot seem to find this setting and was wondering if anyone knew if it existed.

GitHub has this as an available PR restriction:

[image: GitHub sample]

Comment: How about the issue, is there anything to update?

Comment: Sorry @LeoLiu-MSFT this fell off my radar. I'll look into it again and get back at you!

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT is does seem like build validation does the trick! Thanks for keeping on top of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you enable a build validation it will have the same behaviour as the one you describe.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation

Comment: The documentation doesn't really imply that though. I'm not saying I doubt you, but the only information given there is that your build passes.

Comment: I could see it as making a build step where you do like a `git status` and see if there's upstream changes... But that seems way more involved than a simple checkbox.

Comment: no, read the checkbox, it will only work if you got status checks. which is literally the same

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Branch PR Policy - Require Source Branch Be Up-To-Date

Indeed, there is no such directly option or description about this feature in Azure devops.

But after we are familiar with the branch policies for azure devops we will find an alternative, that is what 4c74356b41 said, add a [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation):

> Set a policy requiring changes in a pull request to build successfully
>   with the protected branch before the pull request can be completed.
>   Even if you're using continuous integration (CI) on your development
>   branches to catch problems early, build policies reduce build breaks
>   and keep your tests results passing.
>
> **When a build validation policy is enabled, a new build is queued when
>   a new pull request is created or when changes are pushed to an
>   existing pull request targeting this branch. The build policy then
>   evaluates the results of the build to determine whether the pull
>   request can be completed**.

If a direct option is your ultimate goal, you could add a uservoice [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

[image]

Hope this helps.